# На одном и том же сайте одни id собирает, а другие нет. Как быть?

Tags: python, python-3.x, html5, python-2.x, beautiful-soup

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему на одном и том же сайте www.myscore.ru/snooker, при одинаковом коде, одни `id` собирает, а другие нет.

Если собирать первый вариант (зеленое подчеркивание), все ОК, код:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_open = urlopen('https://www.myscore.ru/snooker/').read()
id_match = BeautifulSoup(html_open, "lxml")

with open('id_match_myscore.txt', 'w') as f:
    for tag in id_match.find_all('div', {'class':'container__main'}):
        if 'id' in tag.attrs:
            print(tag.attrs['id'])
            f.write('\n' + '\n' + 'id')`
```

Если пытаюсь собрать другие `id` (красное подчеркивание), то ничего не собирает, хотя код тот же, пробовал по `title` или по `class` также, варианты:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_open = urlopen('https://www.myscore.ru/snooker/').read()
id_match = BeautifulSoup(html_open, "lxml")

with open('id_match_myscore.txt', 'w') as f:
    for tag in id_match.find_all('div', {'class':'event__match event__match- 
-scheduled event__match--twoLine'}):
        if 'id' in tag.attrs:
            print(tag.attrs['id'])
            f.write('\n' + '\n' + 'id')
```

или то же самое, но по `title`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_open = urlopen('https://www.myscore.ru/snooker/').read()
id_match = BeautifulSoup(html_open, "lxml")

with open('id_match_myscore.txt', 'w') as f:
    for tag in id_match.find_all('div', {'title':'Подробности матча!'}):
        if 'id' in tag.attrs:
            print(tag.attrs['id'])
            f.write('\n' + '\n' + 'id')`
```

[image: Код сайта]

Comment: Лучше вообще в таких случаях пользоваться lxml напрямую с xpath.

Comment: "Лучше вообще в таких случаях пользоваться lxml напрямую с xpath" по-другому никак не получить доступ к этим id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что эта страница уже изменена (вероятно она генерируется динамически), а ни значение атрибута `title`, ни атрибута `class`, которые вы задали, уже не существуют.

Посмотрите, я изменил часть вашей программы чтобы получил *все* значения *всех* атрибутов `title` во `всех` тегах `<div>`:

```
for tag in id_match.find_all('div'):
    if 'title' in tag.attrs:
        print(tag.attrs['title'])
```

и получил только 3 значения:

> ```
> закрыть окно
> Поиск
> Настройки
> ```

Вашего значения `Подробности матча!` там нет.